What is the minimum number of pennies that needs to be chosen from a collection so that the restriction is met?
"Discrete mathematics with applications" by Susanna S. Epp contains the following problem:

A penny collection contains twelve 1967 pennies, seven
1968 pennies, and eleven 1971 pennies. If you are to pick
some pennies without looking at the dates, how many must
you pick to be sure of getting at least five pennies from the
same year?

I consider the worst-case scenario. I get 12 (1967 pennies), then 11 (1971 pennies), and then I am bound to get 5 (1968 pennies). Therefore, you have to choose 12 + 11 + 5 = 28 pennies to be sure to get at least 5 of each year. Is this solution correct?

You are asked only to get $5$ from a single (unspecified) year.  Hence, the worst case would be $4$ from each year.  You appear to be solving a different problem, namely getting at least $5$ from each of the three years.

As @lulu pointed out in the comments, I've been considering a problem of getting at least 5 coins of each year, therefore my solution is wrong.
The answer to the problem stated in the book would be: 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 = 13. In the worst-case scenario, you get 4 coins of one of the three years, then 4 coins of another year, then 4 coins of the remaining year. After that, choose one coin.
